# Assert Equals in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need some help in `assertEquals` in Selenium webdriver.

This is my code:

```
String getHomePageState=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav-menu']/ul/li[1]")).getAttribute("class");
assertEquals("home-bttn active-bttn",getHomePageState);
```

How do i write the code to consider the space in `assertEquals("home-bttn active-bttn"...`

Answer (score 0):

Get the class name via `getAttribute()`:

```
String className = selenium.getAttribute(".//*[@id='nav-menu']/ul/li[1]/@class");
assertEquals("home-bttn active-bttn", className);
```